# get cookies from a website

Tags: selenium, cookies

What are the ways of getting the cookies from a website from ways other than the following?

- Inspecting the browser
- Using Selenium web drivers by using `driver.get_cookies()` command

Answer (score 0):

you can also run javascript via selenium and use document.cookie.
it return the cookies in string format:

key=value;key=value